# how to make space between two points in linechart

Tags: android, achartengine, linechart

[image]

I already did this with no use:

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
mRenderer.setYLabels(12); 
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(5.5f);
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1, "0");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2, "1");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3, "2");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4, "3");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(5, "4");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(6, "5");
mRenderer.setXLabelsPadding(10f);
```

how to add space in the xaxis.

Comment: give [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13014409/1777090) a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setXLabels](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#setXLabels(int)) to give the space between X-axis.

> setXLabels : Sets the approximate number of labels for the X axis.

You have given it 0. You need to give any number > 0 depending upon your requirement.

So Use :

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(5);
```

instead of

```
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
```

Comment: if i do that it will generate random values

Comment: but setXLabels is meant for *setting the approximate number of labels for the X axis* . It should not affect the values I guess

Answer (score 0):

Try with tuning these values:

```
            renderer.setLabelsTextSize(Utils.getPxFromDp(14));
            renderer.setBarSpacing(0.1f);
            renderer.setXLabelsColor(labelColor);
            renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
            renderer.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            renderer.setMarginsColor(activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            renderer.setMargins(new int[]{0, 0, 0, 0});

            renderer.setZoomEnabled(false, false);
            renderer.setPanEnabled(false, false);
            renderer.setXLabels(0);
            renderer.setYLabels(0);
            //renderer.clearXTextLabels();
            renderer.setInScroll(true); 
            renderer.setOrientation(Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
```